# Is the song supposed to be a reference?

Tags: analysis, castle

In the [**Castle**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1219024/) episode ['*Disciple*' (S06E09)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3258212/):

> Castle and Beckett eventually come to the conclusion that Kelly Nieman played a part in the murders, and go on to discuss about it at the loft while Castle is playing with a pen found at her abandoned office. This pen, he finds, holds a flash drive. When he plugs it in, he finds an audio file. It's a song, one that scares the shit out of Beckett. She is visibly shaken.

The song is called "**We'll Meet Again**" by **Vera Lynn**. Do we know the significance of this? It cannot simply be Dr. Neiman taunting Beckett. She would not have been *so* shocked and acted *so* broken. And since 3XK always troubled Castle more than Beckett, I have a hunch that song is somehow related to her **mother**.

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing (11.21.2013, or 21.11.2013 for our European visitors), there isn't a definable meaning available. Most blog posts and references that I can find speculate in one of two directions:

1. Mother - It's related to her mother, and that is why she looks so shaken.
2. Recurrence - It's a thinly veiled allusion that a serial killer has returned, and may possibly be stalking her personally.

In either case, there is nothing proven yet, only speculation.

Comment: The 3XK story arc is over and I'm still not sure of it's significance. I probably missed something, as I haven't been completely faithful to the show. I would appreciate it if you updated  your answer.